# Recurring task in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service where I need to call a function every X minutes. I can make that function as a REST endpoint if that makes it simpler.

I know that creating any sort of timers inside the ASP.NET application would work poorly since the backend is not guaranteed to run at all times when there are no incoming connections.

So what are my options here? I know about the Scheduler Job in Azure, but to trigger more often than 1 hour I would need the paid version, and $12 per month to trigger essentialy implement a timer is to expensive, especially since I need several of them.

Comment: How about Azure Functions (with timer trigger)? Under consumption plan you will only pay for the times when the function is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience, [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) or [Azure Webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs) time trigger may be suit for your case.

**Demo code**:

```
// Runs once every 5 minutes
public static void CronJob([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo timer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cron job fired!");
}
```

**Note:** if using Webjob need to set **Always on** from the [Azure WebApp appsetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-settings).

Comment: Azure functions seems like a great fit for what I'm doing here :)